# Make Sublime Text work with Cakephp (ctp) view files

Tags: cakephp, sublimetext3

I'm trying to get Sublime Text 3 to work well with Cake's ctp (view) files. The syntax highlighting works fine out-of-the-box, but I can't get the HTML autocomplete to work.

If I open an **.html** file, I can get the tags and attributes to autocomplete (except in the attribute "style", it doesn't autocomplete CSS styles).

However, if I work on a **.ctp** file, autocomplete doesn't work at all. I've already tried changing the *View->Syntax* settings to both PHP and HTML and nothing... I've even tried using the *"Open all with current extension as..."* with no result.

I've tried using different plugins (ApplySyntax, cakephp plugins, etc) with any success.

Another thing I've noticed, also for javascript code, is that for "short" tags and functions, if I place the cursor at the opening tag or {, the closing tag or } gets automatically highlighted. However, if there's a bunch of lines of code in-between (same language) then the highlight won't happen...

Any help with these things would be really appreciated! I really want to like and use Sublime!

Comment: This link may help you: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6932

Comment: @Kai thanks, I actually tried with that plugin already but it didn't help...

Comment: Could you point us non-Cake users to a sample `.ctp` file to use for testing? I suspect I know what the answer is (it involves hacking a bit of Sublime's internals), but I'd like to be able to test it first. Just posting a gist on Github should be fine.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for your comment, a `.ctp` file is exactly like a HTML file, it can have both HTML and PHP code (the latter between `<?php ... ?>` of course). It has no custom tags or anything like that, just plain HTML and PHP.

Comment: @Albert OK, thanks. Is autocomplete working for you in regular `.php` files, whether with PHP or HTML syntax? What I mean is, could you rename your `.ctp` to `.php` and have HTML autocompletion work again?

Comment: @MattDMo if I rename the file to `.php` the HTML autocompletion  still doesn't work, and PHP autocompletion does work (it works also with the `.ctp` extension)

Comment: @Albert would you like to [join me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62146/chat-between-mattdmo-and-albert) instead of clogging up the comments? I just want to nail down exactly what you're seeing when, and see if we can get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just install the [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) plugin for sublime-text.

**ApplySyntax can be installed in a variety of ways:**

- Through Package Control http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control

  Open Package Control
  Select 'Install Package'
  Find and select 'ApplySyntax'
- By cloning this repository in Packages

  ```
  cd into your Packages folder
  git clone git://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax.git .
  ```
- By downloading the files and placing them in a directory under Packages, such as ApplySyntax or User

  If you don't put the files in Packages/User (you *can*, but probably shouldn't), make sure they live in Packages/ApplySyntax. If you download and extract a compressed archive from GitHub, the directory will be `facelessuser-ApplySyntax`. Remove `facelessuser-`.

*Courtesy for installation steps:* https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax/blob/master/readme.md

**N.B:** I installed it and now the `*.ctp` files are displayed with proper syntax-highlighting for me.

Update:

In Sublime Text 3, you don't have to use the plugin, you can use the following solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35297789/749232

Comment: I needed to add another ctp entry in the PHP of the settings file. But the other solution looks better (No need for a plugin) for the latest version, maybe that should be an updated accepted solution.

Comment: This is no longer needed.  See other answer.

Answer (score 61):

**NO NEED FOR A PLUGIN NOW!**

In the latest version of SublimeText 3 (at least), you can open a CTP file, then:

> View  ->  Syntax  ->  Open all current extension as  ->  PHP

Then just close your open files, and when you re-open them, they'll be highlighted like the language you chose for that extension.

Comment: A perfectly timed answer: just yesterday Sublime Text updated and seems to have overwritten this setting. "Open all current extension as" is at the top of the Syntax dropdown.

Comment: LOVE IT. Been doing  *Ctrl + Shift + P > Set syntax: PhP* every time I open a .ctp

Comment: @Sweet Chilly Philly - Always nice to hear an answer helped someone! :)